# Alternatives for a "which" pointing to the mentioned idea

Tags: relative-clauses, free-relative-clauses

I wrote:

> Considering this navigation direction, context variables can capture the hierarchical and sequential relations between two patterns, **which** in languages like XPath are explicitly shown using axis specifiers.

*which* actually points to the idea that mentioned in the previous clause *context variables can capture hierarchical and sequential relations between two patterns*.

First I would like to know if I used *which* correctly.

Second, I would like to know the alternatives, if better, for that like,

> .... a feature that in languages like....
>
> .... something that in languages like....
>
> .... other common phrases...

This is another example:

> I think it's because their entries reveal their passion for writing or using words, **which** in turn stimulates my own zeal for writing.

Comment: Add your previous sentence to your question.

Comment: @LawrenceC I meant the previous clause, and mentioned it now.

Comment: It is also possible  to say "Considering this navigation direction, context variables can capture the hierarchical and sequential relations between two patterns, which **relations** are explicitly shown using axis specifiers in languages like XPath".  The relative can be accompanied by the antecedent noun. If **relations** was not the antecedent, then your sentence is not clear to begin with.

Comment: @tromano I added another example, maybe the bare which is the best option if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Unclear antecedent, Ahmad.  What is it that stimulates your own zeal? The fact that they are passionate about writing? The fact their entries reveal their passion for writing?

Comment: Try that sentence without the word **because** and with the word **that** in its stead, and see what you can make of it.

Comment: @TRomano In fact, that sentence is not mine and is written by a learner. Anyway, I think *the fact that their entries reveal their passion for writing* stimulates the writer. Because it is what she observes and feel. Otherwise, she doesn't get aware if they are passionate for writing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a reader/listener will always first assume *which* goes back to the closest noun or noun phrase.  So *which* will refer to "patterns" here.

But you can reword your sentence like this so *which* is pointing properly.  You can also use double dashes to set off the phrase more clearly.  Consider using parentheses to further set apart the phrase if this information is more of an "add-on" in nature than crucial to understanding what context variables can do.

> Considering this navigation direction, context variables--which in languages like XPath are explicitly shown using axis specifiers--can capture the hierarchical and sequential relations between two patterns

or

> > Considering this navigation direction, context variables (which in languages like XPath are explicitly shown using axis specifiers) can capture the hierarchical and sequential relations between two patterns

Comment: I modified the question title. I mean  *which* points to the whole phrase, the concept or feature

Comment: I do not understand you comment to LawrenceC, Ahmad. Your  question is not at all clear.  Where is this phrase you mention, "the concept or feature"?

Comment: @tromano your comment on my question to use *which relations* almost works. I mean the whole phrase whatever you call it, feature, concept, task, thing... however it seems you mean I should always find a noun in antecedent clause, while I look for a pronoun for the whole phrase.

Comment: No, you do not always need to find an antecedent noun; but if you're referring back to the idea, the statement in the relative clause must relate to the idea expressed in the prior clause. Here, you have "context variables can capture" being paralleled with "which...are shown". It doesn't work.  The first clause is transitive, the second is passive.  Also, the ideas of "capture" and "show" make little sense in relation. The idea is not clear.

Comment: @TRomano thank you, I didn't notice this comment because I wasn't notified (needs @Ahmad). You mean such using of *which* is permitted but the two clauses should have almost the same structure and convey similar meaning.